# Program using tokens and privileges

Tags: c++, security, methods, token

I want to create a C++ program with limited privileges.  I made some research on the internet and found out that I have to create a token and then use the AdjustTokenPrivileges() method to alter its privileges.

However, I didn't quite understand how this is to be done.  Can someone please provide me with an example of how to create a token and disable its privileges?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out the example at [Executing Privileged Operations Using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ? Seems like you just need to figure out which tokens are which after using the GetTokenInformation() function, and then disable some of them.

[EDIT]
Explaining in a bit more detail.

- The first call to GetTokenInformation() gets you the length of your token priveledge info object, in bytes.
- Then you actually build a buffer of that size on the heap.
- The second call retrieves the token information object and stores it in your buffer.
- Then you re-cast your buffer to TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*, which allows you to interpret it correctly.
- Then you loop through the Privileges member of this object and set the different attributes to allowed.

Here are [specifics about the TOKEN_PRIVILEDGES structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For each member of Priviledges array, you can look up the name of the priviledge using [LookupPrivilegeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a list of [Priviledge names and descriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

After you know what priviledge it is (i.e. by checking the name), you can set the Attributes of the Priviledges[i] member to one of

- SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED
- SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT
- SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED
- SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS

In your case, I recon it will be mostly the third.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I am quite new to tokens and don't have an idea where to start.  I have learned C and C++ on my own and the majority of these concepts are relatively new to me :s