# Getting Token Information

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi, token

I have the following program written in C:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    char buffer[1000];
    int size = sizeof(buffer);
    PDWORD required_size;

    printf("----Application Privileges----\n\n");
    printf("In this program, we are going to obtain information about the application privileges\n\n");

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId()); //Opening the current process
    HANDLE token; //Creating a handle for the token
    OpenProcessToken(process, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token); //Opening the process token

    GetTokenInformation(token, TokenPrivileges, buffer, size, required_size); //Obtaining the token information
    printf("The following information was obtained with regards to the token privileges: \n\n");
    printf("%s\n\n", buffer);

    printf("Press enter to exit the program");
    getchar();

}
```

Now, I am relatively new to the use of tokens.  When I try to execute the program, the following error comes up:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'required_size' is being used without being initialized.

How can I solve this problem please?  What I want to do is to display information about the token privileges of the current process to the user.

I don't know exactly what the last variable (ReturnLength [out]) in the GetTokenInformation method does.  I tried reading the msdn documentation but did not understand its use.

Comment: Sorry, I edited a previous question and forgot to change the tags :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [example and detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291292/program-using-tokens-and-privileges/13291358#13291358) I gave you again. You need to find the length of the buffer first. Then initialize your buffer to exactly the size of the TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure that you get. Here's the line that does initialization:

```
BYTE* pBuffer = new BYTE[dwLen];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)  I am having a little bit of a problem to display the information retrieved in the buffer.  For some reason or other, only meaningless rubbish information is being displayed on the screen.  For now, I just want to display the token information.  Please bear with me.  I am learning all of these things on my own, this is why sometimes I find it hard to understand some concepts.

Comment: If it still gives you trouble after you initialize and try to loop through the privileges, please edit your question an post the new code. Then we can attempt to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `required_size` parameter is an "out" parameter, meaning that it returns information to you from the function (i.e. an extra return value).  You're supposed to pass it the address of an existing `DWORD` variable, and it fills in the data there, but you're passing it an uninitialized pointer which it tries to write through.

Your code should look like this:

```
DWORD required_size;
GetTokenInformation(..., &required_size);  // Pass address of required_size
// required_size now contains the required size of the data buffer
```